# Has Matéo Maximoff's book Die Ursitory been translated to English?

Tags: language, book, german, folklore

I've been unsuccessfully searching for a book called Ursitory by Matéo Maximoff. From what I have gathered so far, it seems to only be available in German (Die Ursitory) and in French (Les Ursitory). Please, if anyone has any knowledge on where to purchase or rent an ENGLISH version, I would be very grateful. I (THINK) it was written in 1954.

[image]

Comment: Abe Books (https://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/ursitory/author/maximoff-mateo/) lists a copy for sale.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your title question is "Yes": an English translation was  published in London by Chapman & Hall in 1949.  It seems to have been originally published in 1946 in French, with subsequent translations into German (1954), Dutch (1955), Swedish (1957), etc.  You can read all about these various editions on [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/les-ursitory-the-ursitory-a-novel/oclc/752996958/editions?referer=di&editionsView=true)

Some libraries holding copies of the English translation are listed [here](https://www.worldcat.org/title/les-ursitory-the-ursitory-a-novel/oclc/752996958&referer=brief_results).  Depending on where you live you might be able to visit one of them, or ask for an interlibrary loan.

The Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9o_Maximoff) gives some info about the author.